# Sending data to Mysql through a showprompt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would like to send data that the user the filled in a show prompt box. I originally planned to send the data from a regular form, but changed my mind and want to do it through a show prompt box.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_prompt()
{
var name=prompt("question");
if (name!=null && name!="")
  {
  document.write("<p>This is your question " + name + "</p>");
  }
}
</script>
```

the html for the form is:

```
<form id="propose" name="input" action="insertpropose.php" method="post"><br/>
<input type="submit" onclick="show_prompt()" value="propose" />
</form>
```

and the PHP is

```
$query="SELECT propose* FROM propose";
$result=mysql_query($query);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM propose");
```

I m new to programming, so I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something to this effect:

HTML:

```
<form id="propose" name="input" action="insertpropose.php" method="post"><br/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="show_prompt()" value="propose" />
    <input type="hidden" name="propose" value="">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_prompt()
{
var name=prompt("question");
if (name!=null && name!="")
  {
  //set the hidden input value to the value entered in the prompt
  document.input.purpose.value = name; //document.input referring to the form named 'input'
  document.input.submit(); //submit the form
  }
}
</script>
```

Your SQL is a bit wonky, so I changed it to function how I assumed you wanted it to work:

```
$purpose = $_POST['purpose'];
$query="SELECT propose FROM propose WHERE purpose = ". $purpose;
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

Note that using SQL in this way is HIGHLY insecure.

This should give you your desired effect, although this probably isn't the best way to go about doing it.

Comment: I have done that, I still experience some problems. The data put into the prompt box are not sent to my database>